# Rounding the values in a dictionary subject to a constraint

Tags: algorithm, rounding

Toy example: I have an algorithm that generates cake recipes by weight but in order to make them look clean on a website the ingredients need to be rounded to the nearest 50g. The total weight of the cake mix is 1kg.

for example a simple algorithm might be to sort the ingredients by their residual difference to the quantized level and then round each in turn then set the last ingredient to make up the difference to the constraint:

```
cake_1 = {flour: 322g, egg: 100g, sugar: 213g, milk: 189g, butter: 164g, cocoa: 12g} 

cake_1_rounded = {egg: 100g, milk: 200g, cocoa: 0g, sugar: 200g, butter: 150g, flour: 350g}
```

However unless the residual distribution is mean zero this could dramatically affect the value of the last ingredient and so we may wish to distribute the additional weight in a more optimal manner.

Is this a standard problem? if so what is its name? are their objectively better approaches than the simple scheme I described here?

Comment: I understand the part that says that all ingredients need to be rounded to the nearest 50g. But I could not understand the logic of how to make up the difference. What is stopping you from adding 50g to each ingredient instead of the last item only ?

Comment: You could first calculate the rounded weights, then compute the difference between the sum of rounded weights to the target. Afterwards, you can distribute/take away the residual in 50g chunks from each rounded weight in a way that minimizes the difference between the modified rounded weight and original weight. This could probably be done in O(N*log(N)) time if you use a priority queue.

Comment: The term you're looking for is **dithering**. Although that term is usually applied to color matching in computer graphics, the principles are the same.

Comment: The problem that you face is exemplified by the cocoa in your recipe. The amount of cocoa is so small compared to the quantization level that you'll never have a satisfactory result. The nearest quantized values for cocoa are 0 and 50, and neither is a good fit when the exact amount is 12.

Comment: If anyone is going to use these, a second issue is that ratios matter a lot in cooking. For example in buttermilk pancakes the wrong ratio between buttermilk and baking soda will make it acidic or basic, both of which taste terrible. See https://www.amazon.com/Ratio-Simple-Behind-Everyday-Cooking/dp/1416571728 for other examples.

Comment: The cooking example is just to make it easier to understand the question and I exaggerated the quantisation level to make the problems more obvious